# Unity 5.4.0f3 - Can no longer change default sprite resolution?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, resolution

I updated my Unity build last night from 5.3 to 5.4, and now the default settings for my Sprites is grayed out (I can still override for particular platforms).  Now even small textures are defaulting to 2048x2048...  Is this a bug?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Not a bug, you have the Android tab selected in the options. You're probably used to seeing the options available under the standalone tab. If you've got your heart set on changing the Android settings though, see https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporterAndroid.html

Answer (score 1):

Check the checkbox *"Override for Android"*

Answer (score 0):

Oh no!  I am an idiot... you would think that after using Unity for years I would no longer be tricked by its low-contrast UI, but I was again.  All I needed to do was click on the "Default" tab/button that didn't really look like a button.  I think that what happened is when I updated Unity, the default view for the textures tab changed from "Default" to "Android" and this caught me off guard...

[image: screenshot3]